# Get view of a specific child in ExpandableListview

Tags: android, view, expandablelistview

In my Expandablelistview, I have a row to add child manually. So I need to get text of Edittext. By using `getFocusedChild()`, I can get this, but when the edittext is blanck, this row is not focused and I cannot get this view. Finally I get error.
Is there any way to get view of specific child without using focus way?

[This is my Expandablelistview Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guJ7k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views may be get, if they showed on the screen. We can use `expListview.getChildAt(int position)`.